# What is wrong with my long table code?

Tags: longtable, excel2latex

I got the code for the table from excel2latex tool, then I noticed about I need `\longtable` package. After adding the longtable to table environment my code is giving error:

```
\begin{landscape} 
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{8}[0]{*}{77 K}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS : 1 minute &       &       & TS : 1 minute \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & P: 28 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       & TS : 30 minute \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{12}[0]{*}{87 K}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & P: 32 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 1 minute \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & P: 28 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 40 minute &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 20 minute \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & P: 28 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 40 minute \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{8}[0]{*}{97 K}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & DP: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 1 minute &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 1 minute \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 13 minute &       &       &  \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{112 K}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\Delta$P: 8 bar -> 10 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & DP: 8 bar -> 10 > Peq > 25 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 1 minute &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 1 minute \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{127 K}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 1 minute &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & TS: 1 minute \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{RT}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 6 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Adsorption} & $\Delta$P: 4 bar -> 0 > $\mathrm{P_{eq}}$ > 25 bar \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption} & $\Delta$P: 10 bar \\
          &       &       & Ts: 120 minutes &       &       & Ts: 120 minutes \\
    \bottomrule
  \label{tab:meacon}%
\end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
```

The error that I get after trying to compile the code;

```
> LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:meacon' on page 58 undefined on input
> line 178.
> 
> [58] ! Misplaced \noalign. \caption ->\noalign 
>                     \bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ... l.184   \caption
>                 {Add caption} ? 
> 
> Process has been terminated ...
```

What can I do to create such a table ?

Comment: Why all those `\multicolumn`? There's no need to use it for an empty cell; all the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{Desorption}` can simply be `Desorption`, because the column is already specified with left alignment. Anyway, you're missing ``\\`` after `\caption{Add caption}`

Comment: @egreg what should I use for empty cell ? By the way code is running now, the missing thing was     \\, as you said, thanks

Comment: an empty cell is just an empty cell, simply do ` A & & C`, where the letter `B` should obviously be it will be empty.

Comment: You can remove them using `sed`. Do: `sed -e "s:\\\\multicolumn{1}{[lc]}{}: :gi;s:\\\\multicolumn{1}{l}{\([^}]*\)}:\1:gi" <datafile>`

Comment: @zeroth I guess, I need them because if I use only      & it creates a vertical line, that I don' t need.

Comment: Ok. Then it is fine. Just seems like there are too many of them.

Comment: @Yirmidokuz Don't use vertical rules, particularly if you employ `booktabs` commands such as `\toprule` or `\midrule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the `\centering` command does not work in a `longtable` environment, it is replaced by an optional argument `[c]`, as in `\begin{longtable}[c]{format}`.

Secondly you will need to end the `\caption` row with `\\`.

Given that you are using the `multirow` command, you should issue `\\*` at the end of corresponding (sub)rows so that such blocks do not get split across pages.

Instead of inserting blank rows you can add an optional spacing argument to the end of line marker, if you wish.  E.g. `\\[1ex]` or `\\*[1ex]`.

Your vertical rules seem to be inconsistently placed, and can simply be removed.  This obviates the need for most of your `\multicolumn` commands.

Add `\endhead` after the rows you wish to be repeated on subsequent pages.

Your table contains material such as `<` that must be put in math mode.  Numbers with units are best printed via the `siuntx` package.

Here is much of this put together in a version of your table, with just the first block repeated a number of times.  I have not added extra spaces between lines.

[image: Sample partial output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,multirow,lscape,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape} 
\begin{longtable}[c]{lllllll}
  \caption{Add caption}\\
    \toprule
    & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \multirow{8}[0]{*}{77 K}
    & & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{4}{bar} \to 0 > \mathrm{P_{eq}}
    > \SI{10}{bar}$ &    & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P: \SI{4}{bar} \to 0 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{10}{bar}$ \\* 
    & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 > \mathrm{P_{eq}} >
    \SI{25}{bar}$ & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{25}{bar}$ \\*
    & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} & & Desorption &
    $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*  
    & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} \\*
    & & & & & Adsorption & $\mathrm P$: \SI{28}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & & TS: \SI{30}{minute} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{8}[0]{*}{77 K}
    & & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{4}{bar} \to 0 > \mathrm{P_{eq}}
    > \SI{10}{bar}$ &    & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P: \SI{4}{bar} \to 0 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{10}{bar}$ \\* 
    & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 > \mathrm{P_{eq}} >
    \SI{25}{bar}$ & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{25}{bar}$ \\*
    & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} & & Desorption &
    $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*  
    & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} \\*
    & & & & & Adsorption & $\mathrm P$: \SI{28}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & & TS: \SI{30}{minute} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{8}[0]{*}{77 K}
    & & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{4}{bar} \to 0 > \mathrm{P_{eq}}
    > \SI{10}{bar}$ &    & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P: \SI{4}{bar} \to 0 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{10}{bar}$ \\* 
    & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 > \mathrm{P_{eq}} >
    \SI{25}{bar}$ & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{25}{bar}$ \\*
    & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} & & Desorption &
    $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*  
    & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} \\*
    & & & & & Adsorption & $\mathrm P$: \SI{28}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & & TS: \SI{30}{minute} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{8}[0]{*}{77 K}
    & & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{4}{bar} \to 0 > \mathrm{P_{eq}}
    > \SI{10}{bar}$ &    & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P: \SI{4}{bar} \to 0 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{10}{bar}$ \\* 
    & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 > \mathrm{P_{eq}} >
    \SI{25}{bar}$ & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{25}{bar}$ \\*
    & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} & & Desorption &
    $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*  
    & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} \\*
    & & & & & Adsorption & $\mathrm P$: \SI{28}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & & TS: \SI{30}{minute} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{8}[0]{*}{77 K}
    & & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{4}{bar} \to 0 > \mathrm{P_{eq}}
    > \SI{10}{bar}$ &    & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P: \SI{4}{bar} \to 0 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{10}{bar}$ \\* 
    & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 > \mathrm{P_{eq}} >
    \SI{25}{bar}$ & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{25}{bar}$ \\*
    & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} & & Desorption &
    $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*  
    & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} \\*
    & & & & & Adsorption & $\mathrm P$: \SI{28}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & & TS: \SI{30}{minute} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{8}[0]{*}{77 K}
    & & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{4}{bar} \to 0 > \mathrm{P_{eq}}
    > \SI{10}{bar}$ &    & Adsorption & $\Delta\mathrm P: \SI{4}{bar} \to 0 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{10}{bar}$ \\* 
    & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 > \mathrm{P_{eq}} >
    \SI{25}{bar}$ & & & $\Delta\mathrm P$: $\SI{8}{bar} \to 10 >
    \mathrm{P_{eq}} > \SI{25}{bar}$ \\*
    & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} & & Desorption &
    $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*  
    & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} & & & TS: \SI{1}{minute} \\*
    & & & & & Adsorption & $\mathrm P$: \SI{28}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & Desorption & $\Delta\mathrm P$: \SI{10}{bar} \\*
    & & & & & & TS: \SI{30}{minute} \\
    \bottomrule
  \label{tab:meacon}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for very helpful answer, what can I use insted of multirow command ?

Comment: What behaviour do you want?  In some ways it is fine as used here.  A simple alternative is to just place that material in the first row of the block.